# Magento collection bug

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sql

I am a newbie and am trying to get a collection working. I read a lot, tried many things and had no luck.

This is a very basic need.
I am trying to add a column sap_increment_id on my sales order grid but I am being stuck as I can't get it working.

I would like to join sales_flat_order to sales_order_grid with entity.id

The column is displayed but this is not working.

I guess there is a syntax mistake in my JOIN but don't understand too much what the problem is.

Here is what I wrote

```
protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
       $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

       $collection->getSelect()->join(array('address_billing' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),'main_table.entity_id = address_billing.parent_id AND address_billing.address_type = "billing"',array('address_billing.company as billing_company'));

       $collection->getSelect()->join(array('address_shipping' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),'main_table.entity_id = address_shipping.parent_id AND address_shipping.address_type = "shipping"',array('address_shipping.company as shipping_company'));

       $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id', array('sap_increment_id'));

       $this->setCollection($collection);

       return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

**magento 1.9.0.1**

Comment: have you tried to print collection `$collection` using print_r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
            {
                $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                //we changed mysql query, we added inner join to order table
                $collection->getSelect()->join(
                        array( 'order' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order') ),
                        'main_table.entity_id=order.entity_id', 
                        array( 'sap_increment_id' => 'sap_increment_id' ), 
                        null,
                        'left'
                    );
                $this->setCollection($collection);
                return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
            }

            protected function _prepareColumns()
            {

        $this->addColumn('sap_increment_id', array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('sap increment id'),
                    'index' => 'sap_increment_id',
                    'filter_index' => 'order.sap_increment_id'
                ));

// your furthure code
```

Comment: I did update my file with your code. I ve got the Sap_increment_id  column but no results are displaid. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: can you put `print_r($collection); die;`  before `$this->setCollection($collection);` and see result.

Comment: thank you @ kul ve got it working so it is all good for nom. I now need to run a cron to update the records from a csv file. That doesn't seem to be that easy.

Comment: @laurent You can simply add that script to cron using ssh or cpanel.